# c++ SFML Window in std::thread ignore animation

Tags: c++, sfml

I have a main window whose loop is just in the program and a Window class in which separate `sf::RenderWindow` objects are created and the loops for them are in `std::thread`, so when adding a button to such a window, the animation is simply ignored, although if you add exactly the same button to the main window, then everything will work fine.

I run this function in the `std::thread`:

```
void Render() {

    sf::Event event;
    MSG msg = {};

    if (prepare_window_function != nullptr) {
        prepare_window_function(this);
    }

    while (Window_ptr->isOpen()) {

        while (PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE)) {

            if (msg.message == 160) {
                std::ofstream coords("DaTa_hats/_ParamS_/coords");
                coords << Window_ptr->getPosition().x << " " << Window_ptr->getPosition().y << std::endl;
                coords.close();
            }

            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }

        while (Window_ptr->pollEvent(event)) {

            if (event.type == sf::Event::KeyReleased and event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::D) {
                Developer_Mode = 1;
            }
            if (event.type == sf::Event::KeyReleased and event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::Escape) {
                Developer_Mode = 0;
            }

            Handle_Events(event);
        }
        
        Window_ptr->clear(sf::Color(100, 100, 100, 255));

        if (Is_Rendering) {
            Draw_All();
        }

        Window_ptr->display();

        if (Pause_After_Start) {
            Pause();
            Pause_After_Start = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

`Handel_Events` and `Draw_All` are functions from a DLL, their contents are the same as the functions of the main window

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. I forgot to limit the frame rate, after adding:
`setFramerateLimit(60)` it all works fine.